# What does it indicate when the stock price stabilizes around a certain range for many year?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, chart

I was looking at the price history chart of Hindustan Copper Ltd. in [Bombay Stock Exchange website](https://www.bseindia.com) and noticed that for around 2 years the stock price was floating in between Rs. 50 and Rs. 70. What does this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically, a stock price should move if its earning forecast changes. If the earning forecast remains stable - i.e. the company is expected to make roughly the same amount of money going forward - then there's no reason for its stock price to move.

Another factor is dividends. Some companies for various reasons prefer to return excess earnings as dividends. If the entire excess gets paid out as a dividend, the stock price will revert back to its previous value.

Comment: I think the first and second part are more connected than the way you have worded it.  If earnings remain stable then the PE will likely remain stable, but if the company doesn't pay out dividends and instead (e.g.) reinvests in its operations then the value of the company should go up and its stock price along with it.

Comment: Not paying dividends and earnings remaining stable does not necessarily mean that company value should go up.  Earnings may not be much and if perpetuated, share price will go nowhere.

Comment: @Michael note the use of the word "excess". Let's say a stock is priced at X based on earnings expected to be Y. If the company earns exactly Y, there's no reason for its price to change, since Y *is already priced in*. If the company earns Y + some excess Z, it can pay out Z in dividends (in which case its stock price should remain X) or keep the profits ("reinvest") in which case its stock price should grow to X + some function of Z.

Answer (score 1):

Low beta stocks often range trade for very long periods of time (for example, utilities).

Other stocks may fall into this pattern if there  is no fundamental reason (news, good/bad earnings announcements, etc.) creating more buying volume than selling volume needed (or vice versa) to drive price out of the range.  Without such excess buying or selling,  share price just meanders along within a narrow trading range, creating long term support and resistance areas which are frequently tested and fail to penetrate.  And so the meandering continues until it doesn't (some day in the future that news occurs).

Comment: Did you mean "which are frequently tested and hold"? I guess you are imagining potential breakouts failing. If the support or resistance fails, that means the price has broken out of the range.

Comment: Yeh, inartful wording. on my part.  I meant fail as in fail to penetrate,   I'll clarify via edit.